# Rows being multiplied by number of results

Tags: sql, t-sql, sql-server-2008-r2, ssrs-2008

```
SELECT  s.SR_Service_RecID    -- will have 1 result
     ,  p.Description         -- will have 8 results 
     ,  t.notes               -- will have 5 results

FROM SR_Service s
     LEFT JOIN IV_Product p
            ON p.SR_Service_RecID = s.SR_Service_RecID
     LEFT JOIN Time_Entry t
            ON t.SR_Service_RecID = s.SR_Service_RecID
```

This query is multiplying p.Description by t.Notes for the total number of rows. Each p.Description is displaying 5 times against each individual t.notes.

Result set:

```
SR_RecID    Description    Notes
12345       Product 1      Note 1
12345       Product 1      Note 2
12345       Product 1      Note 3
12345       Product 1      Note 4
12345       Product 1      Note 5
12345       Product 2      Note 1
12345       Product 2      Note 2
12345       Product 2      Note 3
12345       Product 2      Note 4
12345       Product 2      Note 5
Etc..
```

I'm unsure how to resolve this one... any help would be appreciated.

[EDIT]:
As the results are correct how can you put this into an SSRS report to show only the correct amount of results as it will display all duplicated rows?

```
SR_RecID
12345

Description
Product 1
Product 2
Product 3
Product 4
Product 5
Product 6
Product 7
Product 8

Notes 1
Notes 2
Notes 3
Notes 4
Notes 5
```

Comment: The query is working correctly, what do u want??

Comment: that is what your query supposed to do, what do you want? a pivot result?

Comment: Obviously, for every `SR_RecID` there's several products and several notes - so what exactly is it that you want? The output from your query looks like the result I would be expecting...

Comment: What of these values: Note 1, Note 2, Note 3, Note 4 or Note 5 you want?

Comment: Thanks all, that confirms it for me. As I'm quite new to this still I wasn't sure if that was correct as it seemed like duplicated information.

Answer (score 0):

If by "resolving" you mean how to only have 1 note for each `SR_RecID` and `Description` then you would need to select only 1 `Notes` for each by using Aggregate function (`MAX`, `MIN`, etc.).

Otherwise, as commented several times, your result is what to be expected.

Comment: Thanks but in this case I will need all results.